# Real calculator in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to make a calculator, but i do not know how to get arithmetic signs
by right way, i get nan because for exapmle + is not a number, but i really can not imagine now how to get it or make it by right way...
I am looking for easy way and only with javascript

```js
var num = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for( var i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ){
 num[i].addEventListener("click", getNum);
  var x = Number(num[i].value);
     var y = Number(num[i].value);
}
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var numsRes = document.getElementById("numsRes");
numsRes.addEventListener("click", getResult)

var plus = document.getElementById("plus");


function getResult(){
 // if(  )
 result.value = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);

}


function getNum(){
 result.value += this.value;
 


 // if( this.value == "+" ){
 //  result.value += this.value;
 // }

}
```

```css
button{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#result{
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <input id="result">
  <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">3</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" value="6">6</button>
  <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" value="9">9</button>
  <button type="button" value="-">-</button>
  <button type="button" id="plus" value="+">+</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="*">*</button>
  <button type="button" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" id="numsRes" value="=">=</button>
  <button type="button" value="C">C</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Takit Isy yeah you have changed it a little, at first there was something which was not written good enough, but now it is better) thank you. I need someone to ask some questions, it will be difficult for you to help me out of stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SO community will be always there to help you when you're writing good questions like this one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `eval()` function to get the evaluated result from a string.
Here is a link for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

You won't need all the buttons to be parameterized to do things, as the whole string will be evaluated when you'll press "=".

Here is a working snippet after modifying your code, and adding the `clear` functionnality:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var num = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  num[i].addEventListener("click", getNum);
  // Deleted x and y vars, not used now !
}

var numsRes = document.getElementById("numsRes");
numsRes.addEventListener("click", getResult);

// Added clear binding
var clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clearRes);

function getResult() {
  // Modified to add "eval()"
  result.value = eval(result.value);
}

// Added clear function
function clearRes() {
  result.value = '';
}

function getNum() {
  result.value += this.value;
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#result {
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <input id="result">
  <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">3</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" value="6">6</button>
  <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" value="9">9</button>
  <button type="button" value="-">-</button>
  <button type="button" id="plus" value="+">+</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="*">*</button>
  <button type="button" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" id="numsRes" value="">=</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear" value="">C</button>
  <!-- The 2 above values are "" to not add characters to the string to be evaluated -->
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying... x and y variables are being set several times at the start (inside the for loop) and never changed after.

This version kind of works... but it's really far away from a full calculator, and that would be far beyond the scope of a single question.

Just press 1+2=

... or 2*456-123=

... or 7*3/2=

... or whatever you wnat

```js
var num = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for( var i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ) {
  if (num[i].id != "numsRes")
    num[i].addEventListener("click", getNum);
}
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var numsRes = document.getElementById("numsRes");
numsRes.addEventListener("click", getResult);

function getResult() {
 result.value = eval(result.value)
}

function getNum() {
 result.value += this.value;
}
```

```css
button{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#result{
  width: 130px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <input id="result">
  <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">3</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" value="6">6</button>
  <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" value="9">9</button>
  <button type="button" value="-">-</button>
  <button type="button" id="plus" value="+">+</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" value="*">*</button>
  <button type="button" value="/">/</button>
  <button type="button" id="numsRes" value="=">=</button>
  <button type="button" value="C">C</button>
</div>
```